# Modal hidden in FF but not Chrome, IE11

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a simple tool that uses PHP, JQuery, and CSS to allow a user to add and edit rows/records in a database.

In Firefox, the system works perfectly. In Chrome and IE11, the modal is never hidden, and the Submit buttons do not show the "Job is updated" modal.

Any thoughts on why FF is A-OK and Chrome and IE11 are not displaying the modals properly?

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/10b4yz5c/), broken because of the PHP that's included... I'm open to suggestions for a better way to present it for review.

Here is the modal HTML:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="jobsModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Job Details</h4>
      </div>
      <form action="add_job_form.php" id="mainform" method="post" name="mainform">

          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="hidden" id="job_id" name="job_id" />
            <input type="text" id="job_title" name="job_title" placeholder="Job Title" />
            <textarea id="position_summary" name="position_summary" rows="5" placeholder="Position Summary"></textarea>
            <input type="text" id="duty1" name="duty1" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 1" />
            <input type="text" id="duty2" name="duty2" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 2" />
            <input type="text" id="duty3" name="duty3" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 3" />
            <input type="text" id="duty4" name="duty4" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 4" />
            <input type="text" id="duty5" name="duty5" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 5" />
            <input type="text" id="duty6" name="duty6" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 6" />
            <input type="text" id="duty7" name="duty7" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 7" />
            <input type="text" id="duty8" name="duty8" placeholder="Duties &amp; Responsibilities 8" />
            <input type="text" id="edu1" name="edu1" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 1" />
            <input type="text" id="edu2" name="edu2" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 2" />
            <input type="text" id="edu3" name="edu3" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 3" />
            <input type="text" id="edu4" name="edu4" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 4" />
            <input type="text" id="edu5" name="edu5" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 5" />
            <input type="text" id="edu6" name="edu6" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 6" />
            <input type="text" id="edu7" name="edu7" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 7" />
            <input type="text" id="edu8" name="edu8" placeholder="Education &amp; Experience 8" />              
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="password" id="passcode" name="passcode" placeholder="Please enter your passcode"  style="float: left; width:80%; height:35px;" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" id="toggle-save" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your "Close" button an input element:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close" />
```

Or you can add javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#btnId').click(function () {
    $('#jobsModal').modal('hide');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Neither of those worked, unfortunately. The modal always is visible and will not close with either of the suggestions you listed.

Comment: Is the close button not working for you? Or is it just the submit button that is not acting the way you want? If close button is not working, is it displaying an error in the chrome console?

Comment: Edit: Chrome is now working. Thanks for the help on that! Do you know of any "webkit" fixes for this issue?

Comment: My apologies, this looks to be an issue with internal firewall policies. I am marking your answer as the solution.